# Gerrit 2.12 upgrade cannot login anymore

Tags: oauth-2.0, gerrit, google-oauth

After upgrading Gerrit to 2.12.2 I can no longer login.
In the logs I get the following exception:

```
ERROR com.google.gerrit.pgm.http.jetty.HiddenErrorHandler : Error in GET /login/
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Username cannot be changed.
        at     com.google.gerrit.server.account.ChangeUserName.call(ChangeUserName.java:78)
```

I'm using Oauth2 with a Google domain and an Apache frontend handling this for me.
My gerrit auth config is:

```
...
[auth]
        type = HTTP
        emailFormat = {0}@revault.ch
        httpHeader = X-Forwarded-User
...
```

The gerrit database has been migrated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the culprit was the mappings in the table account_external_ids.

You can inspect it through gsql:

```
ssh gerrit.example.com gerrit gsql
gerrit> select * from account_external_ids;
```

In my case I had multiple entries starting with username: for the same account.
After clearing out the ones not necessary with a command like this

```
ssh gerrit.example.com gerrit gsql
gerrit> delete from account_external_ids where account_id = 1000032 and external_id='username:superfluousmapping';
```

and after flushing the caches

```
ssh gerrit.revault.ch gerrit flush-cashes
```

I could login again.